# HTML5 FileSystem API List Files in Directory Simple Example

Tags: html, api, filesystems, directory

Could anyone provide me with a very basic example of how to list the files located in a local directory using the HTML5 FileSystem API?  I would like to be able to use an HTML input element of type "file" to select which directory's content is listed off. I tried using the example from the link below, but it did not work (screen was blank and nothing was listed).

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 File System - How to read directories using directory reader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234515/html5-file-system-how-to-read-directories-using-directory-reader)

Answer (score 1):

Just add some attribute to your input tag!

Ex:

```
< input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple webkitdirectory="" directory=""/ >
```

Then you can see what content is in this folder.

Comment: Unfortunately those are not in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

This question - [Get metadata of local mp3 file using html5 filesystem api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425007/get-metadata-of-local-mp3-file-using-html5-filesystem-api) - has a simple example that lists all the files in a specified directory. The HTML5 Rocks sample appeared to only be matching/outputting on specific file types, which was possibly why you saw an empty result