# Get metadata of local mp3 file using html5 filesystem api

Tags: jquery, html, filesystems, mp3, metadata

I was trying to get the title and artist (and other metadata eventually) of each mp3 file in a directory.  Currently the code I have appends the div "thelist" with the file name of the mp3 file.  How could I go about getting the title and artist properties/tags of the file instead of the entire file name?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Get Directory</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#file-input").on("change", function(e){
  var thefiles = e.target.files;
  $.each(thefiles, function(i, item){
    var thefile = item;
    $("#thelist").append("FILES: " + thefile.name + "<br />");;
  });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="file-input" webkitdirectory="" directory="">
<div id="thelist"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you'll need to use the FileReader to grab each file in turn, and extract the data from the ID3 tags using that - http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

Is this something where you are reading files off the server (ie could you do this server side where there are more options) or are you trying to read from the users machine, which will be more of a challenge...

**Update:** See the jsFiddle referenced in my comment below (1/22) for a working sample that incorporates the code from above and the jDataView subroutine.
It only works with .mp3 files, and those have to have valid ID3 tags in (I edited a few mp3 files in VLC to make sure they were okay, iTunes wasn't doing the trick).
Only tested in Chrome on OSX but hopefully enough to get you started, though remember the HTML5 implementations vary browser to browser and platform to platform

Comment: I am trying to get the file names of every file in a directory and then read the metadata of mp3 files using Javascript/jQuery.  I am very new to using the filesystem API so if anybody knows where to find a complete example or could easily make an example themself that shows each of these processes separately or both of these processes in sequence in a very basic context it would be VERY helpful.

Comment: Thanks, the example works great.  The only problem I am running into is that when I try to get the tags from a directory with over about 100 files, the browser then crashes.  I am using the newest version of Chrome.  The "Aw, snap. Something went wrong while trying to display this web page. To continue reload or go to another page" page shows up. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Should I get the total count of files in the directory and then split them into groups of less than 100 and retrieve their tags group by group?  Or is there a simple trick to handle this?

Comment: you'll probably want to split into smaller groups and make sure you're freeing resources as you go - I didn't spend much time optimizing the solution for things like garbage collection

Comment: I have gotten this to work for directories with 200-300 files in it, but it still crashes with directories with more files than that. How would I go about making this work for directories with 1000+ files? Is it possible? Is my method of grouping logical and effective? Does the setTimeout function I have added at the end of the second each loop help with the reading of a large amount of files?
Heres the link to a jsFiddle of my code: [jsFiddle Code Page](http://jsfiddle.net/35Rkd/)

Comment: are lines 61-63 needed? also when finished with the dv you might want to set it to nothing (helps garbage collection). Also the var reader can probably go outside the loop so you only new it once. I don't have a 1000+ file mp3 directory to easily test against but do you get any errors in console log (maybe hook in http://jsErrLog.appspot.com to get a record of what's happening)

Comment: I removed lines 61-63 -- they weren't needed.  I tried setting the dv object to nothing by diong dv = "", but I don't know if that is correct.  I do not get any errors in the console log when I try to view a directory with a lot of files and the browser crashes.  I tried implementing jsErrLog but the report did not give back any results when I checked it.  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the updated JS Fiddle Page: [http://jsfiddle.net/35Rkd/](http://jsfiddle.net/35Rkd/)

Comment: Or is this a better way to go about going through to read each file for the directory? [http://jsfiddle.net/X6BZe/](http://jsfiddle.net/X6BZe/)

Comment: to be honest unless we can track what the error is it's going to be tough to determine the right fix. if you are running this in Chrome can you use the Task Manager (on the Tools menu) to track and see if it's a memory issue. You may be able to dig into the problem with http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging but I'm no expect there

Comment: How would I get the track number, genre and comment fields?  I tried just adding the dv.getString lines with the length being based on the location of these ID3 fields as stated on this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Editing_ID3_tags but this did not accomplish anything.  Also, is it possible to get the extended ID3 tags with this script?

Comment: Not sure about the additional fields, or the extended ID3 tags ... might be worth checking with the original guy who wrote the script http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript I will see if I can make something work but if I don't update in the next hour I probably haven't had any luck...