# How do I call a list of mp3 files randomly in HTML5/Javascript?

Tags: html, random

I'm not really a coder so please be a little elaborate. I want to know if there's any way I could call a bunch mp3 files in a folder at random. (Or call on the basis of how these files are labelled.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're not a coder, then StackOverflow is not for you. StackOverflow is a community of programmers helping each other out with *specific* problems. If you're not a coder you should either hire one, or try to learn what you're doing yourself. If while you're learning you run into any issues, come back here and [post the code that you're having trouble with](http://sscce.org/), and we'll be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*100));
I'm using this to generate a random number. is there any way I could select different functions based on the random number generated?

Answer (score 0):

I would use code similar to this - [Get metadata of local mp3 file using html5 filesystem api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425007/get-metadata-of-local-mp3-file-using-html5-filesystem-api/14448532) - to select all the files from the directory into an array, then the Math.random to pick entries from the array