# Making an HTML5 Video Playlist for Chromecast with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, chromecast

I'm pretty new with Javascript but know it's capable of some amazing things. I recently got a Chromecast. Among other things it allows me to cast/stream any video or webpage to my TV when I click the Chromecast extension.

So, for example, I can load a video in my browser just by browsing to the file with the url like so: file://localhost/Users/username/Downloads/workaholics.s03e14.hdtv.x264-2hd.mp4. And when I click the Chromecast extension it plays on my TV.

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a playlist somehow for videos to be played this way. But I've read that, for security reasons, Javascript will not supply the path to a file, only the name. I was planning on letting a user browse through or drag and drop files to a playlist, and somehow play them back-to-back. I can't seem to figure out how to implement this. I was planning on getting the full paths to the videos added to the playlist and looping through them to play, but getting the full path is apparently not possible. If this is only run locally, with my local files, is there a workaround for something like this? Or anybody have other ideas?

Comment: you could use the code from the example in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425007/get-metadata-of-local-mp3-file-using-html5-filesystem-api/14448532 to let the user specify the root directory and then parse that to build your own view of the structure below a pre-defined root, but it's hacky...

Comment: Hmm... How about this... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ plus this... http://mediaelementjs.com/ ? I wonder if that would work

Comment: I am going to have to get a chromecast now! You got me curious ;)